# Replicating McDonald's Mocha

Tags: milk, drinks, restaurant-mimicry

recently I've been trying to recreate the mocha they make at Mcdonalds. After many failed attempts. Here is how I currently prepare it:

1. Put chocolate powder and sugar into a cup, pour a little boiling water, beat
2. Heat milk in another pot, mix in coffee powder while boiling
3. After the milk is sufficiently boiled, pour it into the cup

The problem I'm having is that my mocha doesn't have the 'creaminess' that the fast-food chain has... it's a bit too 'smooth'. Yet when I drink the one from Mcdonalds, the drink feels dilute yet more creamy... which is weird because how can you have less milk in the drink yet have it creamy?

Comment: If you are aiming for a very specific texture, it is best to use the work of other people who have tried solving the problem instead of just randomly combining ingredients. The Internet offers quite a few recipes for McDonalds copycat mocha.

Answer (score 1):

The creaminess in many coffee drinks comes from steamed milk. The milk is heated by forcing steam through it. This leads to a very creamy result. It is hard to replicate at home without an espresso machine with a steam wand. You can foam the hot milk with a cappuccino wand (or something similar) for a slightly more authentic result but the result will not be as creamy as properly steamed milk.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to replicate the frothy milk texture of lattes and espressos without an espresso machine. Professional machines use Steam. Cheap machines are lucky to get any steam at all.

- In a microwave safe container, add some milk and seal it and shake it up real good. Then open it carefully, add he cocoa powder and shake it up again and heat it up once more.
  Now add it to your coffee.